# Maildir "new" has messages but Inbox is empty

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, imap, maildir

I'm installing a new mail server (Postfix/Dovecot+Maildir) in a fresh OS.

Using Thunderbird (or Squirrelmail) I can send mails but my inbox is empty even when I can see them in `/home/<mailuser>/Maildir/new`.

What could be the problem? I'll attach any conf file if necessary.

Edit:
The dovecot config is `mail_location = maildir:/%Lh/Maildir/:INDEX=/%Lh/Maildir/`
Like Damiano said, Postfix and Dovecot mail folder didn't match.

Comment: What is the output of `doveconf -a | grep mail_location` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably **not** sharing the same mailbox location/folder and/or mailbox delivery style (MBOX vs. MDIR) in both Postfix and Dovecot. As a result, Postfix is (correctly) writing under "*/home/mailuser/Maildir*" (where you see your mail arriving, under the "new" subfolder), but as dovecot is searching somewhere else... it doesn't find such mails (so you get a "no-mail" from it).

As a first check, you should:

- Postfix: check the home_mailbox parameter in /etc/postfix/main.cf:

---

```
# The home_mailbox parameter specifies the optional pathname of a
# mailbox file relative to a user's home directory. [...]  Specify
# "Maildir/" for qmail-style delivery (the / is required).
#
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

---

- Dovecot: as suggested by @Kondybas check the mail_location parameter (in CentOS 6.5, at /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf):

---

```
# See doc/wiki/Variables.txt for full list. Some examples:
#
#   mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
#   mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
#   mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/%d/%1n/%n:INDEX=/var/indexes/%d/%1n/%n
#
# <doc/wiki/MailLocation.txt>
#
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

---

The two directives above tell Postfix and Dovecot to store incoming mail for "*userN*", whose home-directory is */home/userN*, under the Maildir structure at */home/userN/Maildir*

Things are slightly more complex in case of "virtual" users (users *not* having a proper unix account defined on the machine), in which case both Postfix and Dovecot need to share also the way to get/calculate the home-dir of *userN*

Comment: Thank you!! Turns out Dovecot `mail_location` wasn't set correctly. I ended up installing iRedMail anyway.